# IIS URL rewrite from multiple domains to non-www

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting

I currently have below domains:

```
mydomain.com.au
mydomain.com.sg
mydomain.com.hk
```

I would like to redirect each of them to non-www. so eg.

```
www.mydomain.com.au -> mydomain.com.au
www.mydomain.com.sg -> mydomain.com.sg
```

Any ideas? Can I do this in one regex of do I need multiple for each domain extensions?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `web.config` file inside the `<system.webServer>` node. Just make sure that URL Rewrite module is installed.

```
<rule name="Remove WWW" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*://www.*" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```